# Check if two arrays have same values(they may be with different indexes) c++

Tags: c++

Good evening!
I have a task: implement any function to sort array and then check if two arrays(the input and the output) are the same(meaning that the values are the same). Values in array are random, so there my be something like [5,2,5,5,6,-1,3,0,84305]

I was thinking about checking if elements are in both arrays, then if yes - assign them to some rubbish value(I was hoping to go for NULL, but apparently it works only in Python), and then if any array has something that is not our rubbish value return false, but I am not sure about this variant, maybe someone has better ideas? That would be very helpful

Comment: So say you had to arrays [4, 5, 7, 9] and [4, 5, 7] they would not be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the values are unique, insert all values from the first array in an `std::unordered_set` and remove all values from the second array from it. If your set is empty at the end, or if any removal fails, then the sets aren't "equal" as per your definition.
- If the values aren't unique, you'll need to use an `std::unordered_map` with the value the count of times that particular value was seen. When inserting, you increment the value (or set to 1 if it's the first time you've seen it). When removing, you decrement it. The sets aren't "equal" if you can't find an entry to do the removal step, or if there's any value in the map that's not 0.

Answer (score 0):

So for your sort function, it would be something simple like this

```
  template<typename T, int size>
  auto sort_v(T (&arr) [size])
  {
    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    return v;
  }
```

and then to compare them you could do something like:

```
  template<typename T, int size>
  auto compare(T* arr, T* arr2) -> bool
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      if(arr[i] != arr2[i])
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;

  }
```

Comment: Why not use `std::sort` directly on the array? You can even use `std::begin` and `std::end` on it. An the comparison should really just be a call to `std::equal`.

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes will do that now.

Comment: `std::begin` and `std::end` don't work on pointers. Also `size` in `sort_v` is useless, and `v` doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant to write `void sort_v(T (&arr)[size])`? But then why have a function? Just use `std::sort` directly.

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, i should have written that.

Comment: @Nelfeal I just made `sort_v` so that it was easy for the user, all they have to do is pass in the array and size.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how this works. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1964sqcf7)

Comment: @Nelfeal Isnt it just if you dont do that it decays into a pointer but if use the T (&arr)[size] syntax you are still left with the non decayed array?

Comment: `T (&arr)[size]` declares a *reference*. It's a way of taking an array by reference instead of just taking its address through a pointer (which is what decaying is). `arr` is not the "non-decayed" array, only a reference to it, but functions like `std::begin` (and even `sizeof`) can take that reference as is, and keep `size` intact through template argument deduction. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gn9nzEoaq)